# Handling Keyword Collision in Antlr

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a language that looks something like this:

```
SORT EQUALS,FORMAT=CH
```

I have = defined as

```
EQUALS          : '=';
```

If I define this:

```
EQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];
```

I will have name collision.

Obviously, I could do this:

```
ChrEQUALS          : '=';
EQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];
```

Or this:
    EQUALS          : '=';
    StrEQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];

But then it breaks consistency with my other names.

What are some good techniques that avoid collision, but remain consistent?

Here are the things I have considered:

1 Rename both such that if I ever code EQUALS incorrectly, I will get an error

```
ChrEQUALS    : '=';
StrEQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];
```

2 Prefix all character definitions with 'c'

Comment: Note that rules that start with a lowercase are parser rules: `strEQUALS` should be `StrEQUALS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often prepend `K_` in front of keywords to make a distinction. In your case, that would then look like:

```
EQUALS
 : '='
 ;

K_EQUALS
 : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss]
 ;
```

And if you have a lot of keywords, you could create a bunch of fragments to capture case insensitive letters:

```
EQUALS
 : '='
 ;

K_EQUALS
 : E Q U A L S
 ;

fragment A : [aA];
fragment B : [bB];
...
fragment Z : [zZ];
```

Comment: I like the idea of adding K_ on keywords.  Unless someone comes up with a better idea I will go with that.  I will give it a few days before I mark this as the accepted answer to give some others a chance to comment.  BTW: I think the | in the EQUALS | '=' is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Antlr is case sensitive so,

```
Equals    : '=';
EQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];
```

with the convention that character literals are named using mixed case and strings being all upper case.

Or, perhaps a more precise naming:

```
EQUAL     : '=';
EQUALS    : [Ee][Qq][Uu][Aa][Ll][Ss];
```

if this is just a one-off collision.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it necessary to choose unique names in a grammar you also should think about possible conflicts in the target language (e.g. a token named EOF will certainly give you trouble in C or C++). So the goal should be to make the names as unique as possible (while still keeping them readable).

What I usually do is to [append a _SYM or _SYMBOL to all lexer rule names](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/grammar/MySQL.g#L3963), except for operators, where I use _OPERATOR instead. In addition to those I have lexer rules without this kind of semantic (ID, ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT etc.). Applied to your case you would then have EQUAL_OPERATOR and EQUALS_SYMBOL. If you had a keyword "equal" you could still nicely separate operator and keyword by the given appendixes. Additionally they add clarification in your grammar. A rule like:

```
rule1: A EQUAL B;
```

is not entirely clear about if there is now a '=' expected or the word 'equal'. By using the proper appendix things become immediately clear:

```
rule1: A EQUAL_OPERATOR B;
```

If you have e.g. multiple parsers in an application which define the same rule (e.g. ID) you may even have to add more decoration to your names (e.g. ID_lang1, ID_lang2 etc.).